# Query a multi level nested document at different levels

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in the following format

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "blog": {
      "properties": {
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "subComments": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i have multiple documents with data like

```
{
  "blog_post_id": "blog1",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "c1",
      "user_id": "u1",
      "timestamp": 1487781975676,
      "value": "CVLA1",
      "subComments": [
        {
          "value": "sub comment 1"
        },
        {
          "value": "sub comment 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "c2",
      "user_id": "u1",
      "timestamp": 1487781975686,
      "value": "CVLA2",
      "subComments": [
        {
          "value": "sub comment 3"
        },
        {
          "value": "sub comment 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like match the blog documents which have comment value CVLA1 and a suc comment which has value "sub comment 2".

I wrote a query like

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "comments.value": "CVLA1"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "comments.subComments",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "commnets.subComments.value": "sub comment 2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this one doesn't work as expected. Any help how to query at different levels of a multi level nested document.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in your query around `commnets.subComments.value`. It should be `comments.subComments.value`. So the entire query would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "comments.value": "CVLA1"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "comments.subComments",
                "query": {
                  "match": {
                    "comments.subComments.value": "sub comment 2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I double checked - it works fine for me.